# Problems trying to running Symfony 2.0.14: "Whoops, looks like something went wrong"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to get Symfony 2.0.14 running at my local PC but get this error:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1 InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "framework" (in /var/www/html/symfony/app/config/config_dev.yml). Looked for namespace "framework", found none 
>       in /var/www/html/symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 272
>       at YamlFileLoader->validate() in /var/www/html/symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 242
>       at YamlFileLoader->loadFile() in /var/www/html/symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 42
>       at YamlFileLoader->load() in /var/www/html/symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php line 52
>       at DelegatingLoader->load() in /var/www/html/symfony/app/AppKernel.php line 34
>       at AppKernel->registerContainerConfiguration() in /var/www/html/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 868
>       at Kernel->buildContainer() in /var/www/html/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 784
>       at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /var/www/html/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 518
>       at Kernel->boot() in /var/www/html/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 549
>       at Kernel->handle() in /var/www/html/symfony/web/app_dev.php line 27

Any advice on this? I'm running PHP 5.4.3 in Fedora 16 this is the first time I get this problem :(

Comment: Show us your *app/config/config_dev.yml*.

Comment: @SamyDindane is the default I didn't touch anything but here is: http://pastebin.com/AjQzA0jR

Comment: Open `AppKernel.php` and check that `FrameworkBundle` is enabled in `registerBundle` method.

Comment: @m2mdas you mean this line: new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle()? Yes it's enabled!

Comment: no, `new  Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle()`

Comment: @m2mdas yes it's there too as I said is a untouched install of Symfony just download the .tgz uncompress and nothing else :(

Comment: does php app/check.php output something interesting (in sf directory)?

Comment: @greg0ire seems like a bug or something else because only happens with latest PHP 5.4, I leave the issue at SF github https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4416#issuecomment-5946227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Symfony 2.0.15 on Windows 7 running PHP 5.4.2 (later upgraded to 5.4.4) and encountered the same problem with same error message.

As indicated on https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4416 (opened by ReynierPM), the problem is caused by APC and PHP 5.4.x so disabling APC "fixes" the problem.  It worked by commenting out extension=php_apc.dll in php.ini on Windows for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `php bin/vendors install` and visiting */config.php*.
Also, make sure some of [your files don't end in *.ph*, *.tw*, or *.ym*](http://www.siteduzero.com/forum-83-688459-p1-pb-installation-symfony.html#r6657033).

Answer (score 0):

Did your read **Installing and Configuring Symfony** in symfony2 book? There is described cleary how to configure a fresh symfony2 installation.

[Symfony2 Book- Installing and Configuring Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html)

Major steps:

- make sure you have the correct directory structure
- update vendors if you downloaded without
- setup permissions !very important

Comment: I'm not I newbiew with Symfony and yes I know this steps since I start with SF 1.4 :) in deep sounds rare to me they don't talk about Virtual Host and use localhost instead :o anyway as I comment before "seems like a bug or something else because only happens with latest PHP 5.4, I leave the issue at SF github github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4416#issuecomment-5946227" for now it's being discused there at Symfony Github need to wait for a solution or so. Cheers